# A friend gave me a backup he used for his Samsung Galaxy On5, How do I use these files to 'restore' my Samsung On5?

Tags: restore

```
boot.emmc.win
boot.emmc.win.md5
data.ext4.win
data.ext4.win.md5
data.info
recovery.log
system.ext4.win000
system.ext4.win000.md5
system.ext4.win001
system.ext4.win001.md5
system.info
```

So I'm using Arch linux, I'm familiar with flashing using the heimdall utility(currently using a rom for an On5 that isn't the same as my phone so I can't get audio/camera usage). Also I have TWRP installed. How do I use these files to restore my phone?

Comment: You can flash a backup through a custom recovery(TWRP, CWM...)

Comment: esQmo I'm asking how, when I use TWRP and try recovery, it doesn't show the files.

Comment: They must be placed into the correct directory. On your SD card, that's below `TWRP/BACKUPS/<device_name>/<backup_name>`. `<backup_name>` can be anything, but I'm not sure about the device name. On my tablet, it's e.g. `TWRP/BACKUPS/Lenovo_TB3-710F/2015-12-05--12-55-01_TB3-710F_S000025_160613_ROW` (a name automatically generated by TWRP).

Answer (score 0):

Boot in TWRP and hit Restore. It will show a list of backups, select one and you'll see a list with  System, Data, Boot. Make sure all the boxes are checked and swipe the bar to restore. The restore will take a few minutes, but when it’s finished, you can reboot your phone back into Android. If it asks you to root, be sure to tap “Do Not Install” if you don't wish to.

***Flashing a zip file:***

Tap on Install . browse to the location where you saved the file `2016-09-21_twrp_on5ltetmo_system_data.7z`.
Now at the bottom of the screen, do a swipe on the Swipe to confirm flash option to begin flashing. Reboot the device when finished.

Comment: I added both the .7z file that contains the listed elements and the unzipped file that contains these individual elements, when I go to restore and select the sdcard, it doesn't even list these items.

Comment: From what the backup was made? I mean using what method.

Comment: I don't know, all I have is this zip file  
    2016-09-21_twrp_on5ltetmo_system_data.7z
    
and the files listed above

Comment: Please check my edited post.